# Cannot install Ubuntu within Windows 8.1, BIOS based

Tags: system-installation

When I try to install Ubuntu via bootable USB drive, it displays at the boot time, no operating system detected.
And after that I tried to extract ISO image file of Ubuntu but that too didn't work saying "cannot download metalink and therefore the iso" even if I place ISO and Wubi in same folder.

Comment: The iso should not be extracted but burned to a DVD. And, are you sure you made a bootable USB drive? How? Use Unetbootin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score 0):

You can create USB Boot disk in either `Startup Disk Creator` or [`Unetbootin`](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/):

- **Startup Disk Creator**

Note: `Startup Disk Creator` is included to Ubuntu, so you need either run Ubuntu (on other computer) or boot any machine from USB or CD/DVD Live.

[image]

- [**Unetbootin**](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

`Unetbootin` exists for Linux, Windows, Mac

[image]